# Issue with SQL query Microsoft Office Access Database Engine error '80040e14

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I am using ASP to build a website and need to use an SQL query to search based on a form.
I am however receiving `Microsoft Office Access Database Engine error '80040e14`

The code I am using is

```
searchFor =  Request.Form( "searchFor" )
maxPrice =  Request.Form( "maxPrice" )
minPrice =  Request.Form( "minPrice" )
bedroom =  Request.Form( "bedroom" )
Dim cnnSimple ' ADO connection
Dim rstSimple ' ADO recordset
Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

cnnSimple.Open ("Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("\Final_Project.accdb")) 

sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Details WHERE Price BETWEEN "& minPrice &" AND "& maxPrice &" OR Address_2 LIKE '" & searchFor & "' OR Bedrooms = "& bedroom &" "
```

Before this error, I had also noticed that the `BETWEEN` statement and `=` statement was not affecting the search, even though the values were being taken correctly

On a side note, I am aware that this is vulnerable to SQL injection and am working to get it resolved

Comment: You should include the error description and not expect everyone to spend the time looking up a number. The where clause doesn't do what you want because you need to wrap the two OR conditions in one set of parens. As a side note, Access is not recommended for use with web applications. You would be better off using SQL Server or other server based database engine.

Comment: I understand that Access is not ideal for this but I have limited time and resources and therefore will still stick with Access for now.. The full error is `Microsoft Office Access Database Engine error '80040e14'

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Price BETWEEN 0 AND 0 (OR Address_2 LIKE '' OR Bedrooms = )'.`

Answer (score 1):

It's Bedrooms:

```
OR Bedrooms = '" & bedroom & "'"
```

or, if numeric:

```
OR Bedrooms = " & Nz(bedroom, 0) & ""
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am now getting a type miss match on Nz, `Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'Nz'`

Comment: Nz is a custom function made by Gustav to transform a non-numeric (like empty) value to 0, you can just do your own code to avoid concatenate an invalid value

Comment: Yes, forgot the script angle ... you really should handle variable bedroom before using it in the SQL - set it to 0 or some default value in case of Null.